# How can I find the minimum circuit of graph containing all nodes in a subset of graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, cycle, circuit

Given a weighted undirected graph G = (V, E) and a set of nodes P and a starting node S and subset of nodes P_S.

I want to find the minimum weight circuit in this graph G such that it contains ALL the nodes in P_S. The circuit is allowed to backtrack (i.e. there could be a segment where it's A->B->C->B->A).

We'd thought about relating this to the TSP, but it's slightly different since we're trying to in fact get a circuit, and it's allowed to backtrack. We also considered using Dijkstra's to find the shortest paths between all the nodes that we need (the starting nodes and those in P_S), but that returns a tree which is not a circuit.

How can we find such a circuit?

Comment: Since the nodes and edges are allowed to repeat, this is known as a circuit, not a cycle.

Comment: Yeah, I had meant circuit. My graph theory terminology could use some work.

Comment: Oh huh, I guess that works. I don't know why I couldn't find that post after searching for like half an hour. Thank you.